# Server object error 'ASP 0177 : 800401f3' Server.CreateObject Failed /cs_access/security_module/checkuser.asp, line 27 800401f3

Tags: dll, asp-classic, vb6, windows-server-2008, dllregistration

Hi i am migrating windows 2003 server to windows 2008 server.
I am using classic ASP and VB, i am facing a problem when i try to login.

```
Server object error 'ASP 0177 : 800401f3'

Server.CreateObject Failed

/cs_access/security_module/checkuser.asp, line 27
```

Line 27 is:

```
set objHash = server.CreateObject("DigiSign.Signature")
```

This is the error shown in browser.
I have registered the DLL in `SYSWOW64` and all the DLL's got registered successfully but still facing the issue.

Comment: Which version of VB? Can you show line 27? Do other `Server.CreateObject()` calls work? The more info related to this error, the better.

Comment: this is line 27: - set objHash = server.CreateObject("DigiSign.Signature")

Comment: Did you set  `Enable 32-bit apps` to `True` for the `AppPool` your site is using?

Comment: i tried  that one also, but it gives me 503 service unavailable error.

Comment: Are you saying you're using [tag:vb6] because the DLL was created in VB6 and you have access to the source code *(of the DLL)* or because you mean [tag:vbscript] in terms of the scripting language you are using in [tag:asp-classic]?

Comment: Is the DLL 32 or 64 bit? If it's 64 bit it shouldn't be registered with `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\regsvr32.exe` it should use `%SystemRoot%\System32\regsvr32.exe` instead. *This only applies to 64 bit operating systems*.

Comment: `HTTP 503 Service Unavailable` points to no Application Pool being associated with the web application, make sure an Application Pool uis defined and associated to the web application in IIS.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31645839/692942 *(possibly a duplicate of the same underlying issue?)*

Comment: dll is 32 bit ,so it needs to be registered in syswow64.it's done.

Comment: when i try to enable 32 bit application,application pool get stopped that;s why 503 service unavailable.application pool is defined for my site.